# Syntax error in SQL SELECT INTO FROM from Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to insert a new record into my database using SQL, but it keeps telling me that I have a syntax error in the from clause.

I don't see the error.

Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 sCategoryName :string;
begin
 sCategoryName := InputBox('Category Name', 'Please enter your category name that you would like to add','');
 with dmRecords do
  begin
   qryRecords.Active := False;
   qryRecords.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO [Category of Income]([Category Name])');
   qryRecords.SQL.Add('VALUES ' + '(' + QuotedStr(sCategoryName) + ')');
   qryRecords.ExecSQL;
   qryRecords.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM [Category of Income] ORDER BY [Category ID]');
   qryRecords.Active := True;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: As a sidenote, please stop using concatenated SQL statements, use parameters instead. You are vulnerable to [SQL injection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't cleared the SQL from the previous statement. When you open the query, SQL has three lines of text.

Add `qryRecords.SQL.Clear` before adding the SELECT statement.